# Can't debug in method called in FormMain

Tags: c#

I'm trying to fix an error in my code but it doesn't let me debug through a method. When I start debugging in the `FormMain` it jumps to `Program.cs` and skips the method that is called in the `FormMain`. Can anyone suggest the cause of this

```
public FormMain() {
    #if !DEBUG
    //NativeMethods.BlockInput(true);
    #endif
    InitializeComponent();
    var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => Execute());
    aTimer.Interval = 120000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

public void Execute() {
    int Tijd;
    int Videolengte;
    string resultaat;
    string URL = "";

    Database db = new Database(CONNECTION_STRING);
    object[] result = db.GetFirstRecord();

   // if (result == null)
   // {
   //    return;
   // }
   // else
   // {

    URL = (string)result[1];
    Process browser = Process.Start(@"chrome.exe","http:\\www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + URL);
    Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 15);

    resultaat = (string)result[2];
    Videolengte = Convert.ToInt32(resultaat);
    Tijd = Videolengte;
    // Timer van afsluiten starten.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm, that is normal...

The `Main()` function in your `Program.cs` is the entry point of the application. Therefor it starts debugging there when hitting F11.
Your Form `FormMain` gets called after `Program.cs`

Just set a breakpoint where you need it in the FormMain and wait till it hits it while debugging. Start the debugging hitting F5 instead of F11

An interval of 120000 means it calls your function only each 2 minutes (120k milliseconds). You may want to set it to 5000 (5s) for debugging.

Comment: But it never shows the method i am calling, ill edit my code to the OP

Comment: So what are you trying to debug? `Execute()`? An interval of 120000 means it calls your function only each 2 minutes (120k milliseconds). You may want to set it to 5000 (5s) for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Your  `Execute()` method  it's a callback  method  that it will be invoked later when the interval has elapsed for this  reason uyou can't debug this method  and it seems  not to be called

```
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => Execute());
```

put a breakpoint inside `Execute()`  and `wait for 2 minutes` and your breakpoint will be hitted

```
public void Execute()
        { //here press  F9 to set a breakpoint 
            int Tijd;
            int Videolengte;
            string resultaat;
            string URL = "";
```

Another triks that may be usefull  for you  it's you must be sure that you mainform was launched using `Application.Run(new MainForm);`  which is a blocking  call block  meaning that your application will be alive untill you close your mainfom